# GNUPLOT - How to plot sum function that depends on limit?

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot the following function in gnuplot:

```
f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{x-1} 10^i
```

I tried using `f(x)= (sum [i=1:x-1] 10 ** i)`, but it says "range specifiers of sum must have integer values".
Any idea how can I plot this sum function where the independent variable is in the limits? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Make an integer out of your independent variable. Check `help int`. Maybe needs some changes depending on what exactly you want to have. Try:

```
f(x) = (sum [i=1:int(x-1)] 10**i)
```

Comment: @TarikulIslamPapon Glad to hear! Thanks on StackOverflow = accept and/or upvote...